# Understanding Proof that Interval $[0,1]$ is Compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

On page 44-45 of the notes from http://www.msc.uky.edu/droyster/courses/fall99/math4181/classnotes/notes5.pdf, the author writes in the proof *that the  interval* $[0,1]$ *is compact* that supposing the interval isn't compact, that this implies either $[0,1/2]$ or $[1/2,1]$ isn't compact. How do we know that both $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$ are not compact?

Comment: Perhaps my questions was not clear enough, I understand that supposing [0,1] is not compact implies some interval inside [0,1] is not compact. What I am confused about is why can't [0,1/2] and [1/2,1] both not be compact.

Comment: It says either or, that means one or the other or both.

Comment: Thank you, my eyes seem to have glossed over that.

Comment: I put italic using '_ qzerty_' instead of '$$', and changed tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ are compacts. Now take any open cover of $[0,1]$. This open cover is an open cover of $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. Now you use the compactness of $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ and conclude that $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

The union of two compact sets is compact: An open cover of $A\cup B$ contains a finite subcover of $A$ and a finite subcover of $B$, together a finite subcover of $A\cup B$.

(And Hausdorff is clear, too).