# The closed interval [0,1] is topologically compact

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

> Proposition:
>
> The collection $C=\left \{ \left ( \frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right ):n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \right \}$ is not a cover of $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$
>
> Proposition:
>
> $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ is compact.

However, to show that $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ is compact, it is essential that every cover of a space X contains a finite subcollection that also covers the space X.

This does not seem possible with the information given at hand; to begin with the closed interval $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ is not *covered*.

So two potential means I have in mind:

1. Finding another collection that is a cover of $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ then proceed.
2. Using the fact that a nested sequence of closed intervals $\left [ a,b \right ]$ can be constructed from $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$, the details of the proof of which I am unclear.

Any clarification that could potentially shed gain me further insights is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that a Closed Interval Is Compact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623339/proving-that-a-closed-interval-is-compact)

Comment: I think you're right: with the info that we have in the yellow part, is not possible to prove the closed unit interval is compact. In fact, I don't really understand what's the role of the collection $\;C\;$ in proving that: that seems to be completely unrelated.

Comment: Your "So either..." etc. part is not clear to me: what are you asking **exactly**? How to prove the closed unit interval is compact, or *what*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Proof that Interval $[0,1]$ is Compact.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207884/understanding-proof-that-interval-0-1-is-compact)

Comment: @DonAntonio: It's hardly unrelated. It's more or less a special case, most likely intended to suggest what to do next.

Comment: Read both as propositions completely on their own.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks. Perhaps there's a very, very hidden (to me) clue there, yet I can't see how to use the fact that $\;C\;$ is *not* a cover of $\;I\;$  to prove it is compact...

Comment: Would the collection c=$\left \{ \left [ \frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right ]: n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \right \}$ be a cover for the closed interval [0,1]?

Comment: The collection $C$ in the first statement seems to be aimed at showing that the open interval $(0,1)$ is not compact, because $C$ is a covering that admits no finite subcovering.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't know why you think I am saying that you are supposed to apply it in the proof. I have only said it could suggest how to proceed next...

Comment: Remember: to prove compactness you need OPEN covers, but anyway the answer to your last question is NO, since 0 is not in any of those sets. Now, it seems you're looking for some particular open cover to work with in your proof. You need to prove something for all open covers of you interval, so probably the best way to do it is by contradiction. (You can't cover all possible cases proving them one by one, since they are infinitely many)

Comment: "1. Finding another collection that is a cover then proceed." does not seem to be a right track. To prove compactness you have to work with **any** open cover. To know *one* cover does not help at all.

Comment: @tomasz Isn't "Apply in the proof" and "how to proceed next" one and the same in the context of this question?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Why would that be true? Solving a particular case of a problem often suggests how to solve the general case, but only sometimes is a particular case a part of the proof of the general.

Comment: @tomasz Because the OP wants to prove $\;[0,1]\;$ is compact, and he quotes the fact about $\;C\;$ as a proposition *before* the proposition he wants to prove. One could argue that, being put these propositions as they were, the first one is there to "apply in the proof" or to give a clue as "how to proceed next" in the second prop's proof.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Sure, but it doesn't mean the two are one and the same.

Comment: @tomasz You mean the two phrases? In this context in this very question I think they clearly are, but I suppose that can be a matter of opinion.